# Change voting function to only query from the database once (Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I wrote this code to manage voting on my server, however, I know that 3 queries is not good because it slows down the server. Is this possible to change?

```js
app.post('/api/vote/:id', normalAuth, async (req, res) => {
    let vote = req.body.vote > 0 ? 1 : -1;

    let currentPost = await Posts.findById(req.params.id).lean();
    let index = -1;

    for (let i = 0; i < currentPost.voters.length; i++) {
        if (currentPost.voters[i].user === req.user._id) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (index !== -1 && currentPost.voters[index].vote == vote) {
        return res.send(currentPost);
    }

    let credit = vote === 1 ? 10 : -2;

    Posts.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
        voters: {
            user: req.user._id,
            vote: vote
        },
        $inc: {
            votes: vote
        }
    }, {new: true},).lean().exec().then(item => {
        UserDetails.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, {
            $inc: {
                credit: credit
            }
        }).then(credit => {
            res.send(item)
        }).catch(err => {
            res.send(err)
        })
    });
})
```

Is this possible? The first database call is to check if the user has already done the same vote, and if so, do nothing, this doubles as a way to get the vote. Then, I update the post to increment the votes and add the user as a voter to the voter array, and finally add the credit to the user.

Comment: Did you figure out a way to do this? If so, please share! I'd like to be able to let a user change their vote.

Comment: @sudocity No I did not. This code works though.